# Child elements not getting displayed in ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I have created a inline directive to display comments from a Java-Script Array. The structure of comments array is as follows

```
$scope.comments = [{
                userName:   'TestUser', 
                comment :   'Parent Comment',           
                comments: [ ] //Holds the Replies
                }];
```

I am programmatically adding the replies to **comments** array in the **$scope.comments** array.

The Inline Directive snippet is as follows

```
  <div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
  <div class="media-body">                          
            <h4>{{ comment.userName }} </h4>
            <p> {{ comment.comment }} </p>
    </div>

    <ul ng-if="comment.comments">
      <li ng-repeat="comment in comment.comments" ng-include="'categoryTree'">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </script>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="comment in comments" ng-include="'categoryTree'"></li>
  </ul> 
  </div>
```

When I add the parent comments to **$scope.comments**, they are getting shown. However, when I add reply to **comments** array in the **$scope.comments** array, it is not getting shown.

Also, if I initialize the **$scope.comments** with all comments and replies in **angular.element(document).ready**, they are shown **correctly**

Please let me know where I am going wrong and how to fix it.

**Other Info**
All of this works correctly when I use directive in independent page, but started to get problems when I am using this content in "ng-view"

Comment: I was using the angularJS version //code.angularjs.org/ **1.2.20** /angular.js . When I used //code.angularjs.org/ **1.4.0** /angular.js OR //code.angularjs.org/ **snapshot** /angular.js things are working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was considered as a bug, which has been fixed in the later versions of AngularJS. The above example works fine with AngularJS version 1.4.0